# Remove default help command not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

So I'm trying to remove the default help command from my discord bot but it shows my new one and the old one [(Example Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1vOO.png), even though I have the code that removes it.

So to remove it I'm using

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!',help_command=None)
```

and to replace it I have

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )

    embed.set_author(name='Saint Bot the Third Help Page')
    embed.add_field(name='!remind', value='Reminds Shabby to get a PC', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='!play', value='Gives you a random game to play', inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have also tried using

```
client.remove_command("help")
```

but that did not work either

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right file?

Comment: Yes, changing anything else in the code, such as the description of a command, correctly updates.

Comment: It will throw an error if the image is true, since you are unable to register duplicate commands.
To fix this, simply stop all running python code and start your bot again. The answer being your running the bot twice, one with the new code and one with the old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this again, you will have to write all the errors thrown if there are any,
i have checked this code, and it is working fine.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

client.remove_command("help")

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )

    embed.set_author(name='Saint Bot the Third Help Page')
    embed.add_field(name='!remind', value='Reminds Shabby to get a PC', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='!play', value='Gives you a random game to play', inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Both work fine, just different ways to do it. See my comment on the main post for the solution (majority of the time excluding super duper weird issues)